# Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Nested simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a form which nests store fields within the seller fields. They look like this

```
= simple_form_for @seller, url: pages_path do |f|
  .span3
    h5.capital Personal/Contact Details
    = f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: 'Full Name (Owner/Manager)'
    = f.input :mobile, label: false, placeholder: 'Mobile Phone No.'
    = f.input :landline, label: false, placeholder: 'Landline No. (With STD CODE)'
    = f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: 'Email ID'
  .span5
    h5.capital Store Details
    = f.simple_fields_for :store_attributes do |builder|
      = builder.input :name, label: false, placeholder: 'Store Name'
      = builder.input :address, label: false, placeholder: 'Full Address'
      = builder.input :city, label: false, placeholder: 'City/District', 
      = builder.input :pincode, label: false, placeholder: 'Pincode', class: 'pincode'
      = builder.input :website, label: false, placeholder: 'Website/Facebook Page'
```

And the seller model looks like this

```
class Seller < User
attr_accessible :landline, :mobile, :name, :store_attributes

has_one :store

accepts_nested_attributes_for :store

validates :name, presence: true
validates :mobile, presence: true
validates :landline, presence: true
end
```

Here is my controller code

```
def create
@seller = Seller.new(params[:seller])
@store = Store.new(params[:store])

if @seller.save & @store.save
  redirect_to @seller
else
  render 'home'
end
end
```

And when I submit the form , I get the following error

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in PagesController#create 
>     unknown attribute: seller_id

Please guide me on how this has to be resolved while keeping whitelist_attributes = true.

Many thx.

Comment: how is `@store` defined in your controller?

Comment: @dax I fixed the mass attribute error, and now I'm running into a new error.

Comment: shouldn't it be `f.simple_fields_for :store` ?